# I want To reuse the Style block of First Button for others button too, How should I do?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I write a simple code for MouseEnter effect for a button. There are also 2 other button where I want same effect. Instead of writing the same code again how can I reuse them?

```
<Button Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White"
 Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20" >
                <Button.Style>
                    <Style TargetType="Button">
                        <Style.Triggers>
                            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300"/>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="80"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger>
                        </Style.Triggers>
                    </Style>
                </Button.Style>
            </Button>

            <Button Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
            <Button Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can store your Style in any resource dictionary object such as a `MergedDictionary` in App.xaml or `Window.Resources`:

```
<Window.Resources>
                <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="myStyle">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                            <BeginStoryboard>
                                <Storyboard>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300"/>
                                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="80"/>
                                </Storyboard>
                            </BeginStoryboard>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

And reuse it by creating objects of type `StaticResource`:

```
<Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource myStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
```

Comment: Maybe some explanations as to why it works and why it's recommended could add some long-term value to this code-only answer? Just sayin'

Comment: @CorentinPane it seemed too basic to give any kind of explanation. I couldn't think of any comment which could add value to my answer. But you're right, code-only answers aren't so valuable either. I edited my answer.

Answer (score 2):

**To answer your question**

You can declare your `Style` in a `ResourceDictionary` like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button" x:Key="MyButtonStyle">
        <Style.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Width" To="300"/>
                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.500" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Height" To="80"/>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

By giving a key to it (here, `"MyButtonStyle"`), you can then refer to it from other places using the `StaticResource` markup:

```xml
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
<Button Style="{StaticResource MyButtonStyle}" Content="Common Factor" FontSize="32" Foreground="White" Background="#FF3399FF" Width="250" Height="60" Margin="20"/>
```

**To go further with Styles**

Note that if you don't specify an explict key to your `Style` by removing the `x:Key="MyButtonStyle"` markup, then your `Style` automatically applies to all `Controls` without an explicit `Style` property set. For example, a `Style` defined like this:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="Button">
        <Style.Setters>
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"/>
        </Style.Setters>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

would automatically apply to all `Buttons` in the `Window` which don't have an epxlicit `Style` attribute.